# IOS Quickblox front camera being inverted

Tags: quickblox

I have developed a video call app using QuickBlox framework everything is fine, but when i use my front camera the video is being inverted. I dont find a way to correct it. I dont have control over QBGLVideoView class.

Answer (score 1):

As for now you can flip your view by 180 degrees. In the future there will be an ability to flip by SDK.